# How should I get started in making this 2-D un-animated mobile game?

Tags: android, ios

I am brand new to coding mobile apps. For fun, I'd like to make a mobile game much like the "Can You Escape Games" where you the user taps the screen to interact, opening up different menus and rooms. It is 2-D and requires 0 animation.

I am not sure how to get started. I have some coding experience but still have a lot to learn. Is there a game engine out there that would make my life easier?  Or would it be better if I coded from scratch (and what program should I use? Android Studio, Visual Studio, etc)?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on how complex your game logic is, you could try using standard android stuff like imageView... just keep different screen sizes in mind. position items relative to background image. some onClickListeners, and you should be good for a first try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to learn native development for each platform first and looks like your game can be easily made with native controls, like labels, buttons and imageviews (TextView, Button, ImageView on Android and UILabel, UIButton, UIImageView on iOS).

For Android the best way is to use Android Studio for development.
For iOS use the XCode IDE, but it is only available on devices running Mac OS (OS X).

Answer (score 0):

Udacity has a pretty good course for LibGDX. That would be a perfect start for learning game development.

https://www.udacity.com/courses/ud405